Pie chart scrollable in kotlin android
I am testing a simple code on Android Studio to print a pie chart with a scrollable text below (I set a simple text loop to test the scroll).
However when I set the modifier "verticalScroll" in my column, the pie chart is not printed correctly, only the legend and the datas (but I can scroll the text...).
If I remove the "verticalScroll.rememberScrollState()" attribute, the pie chart is printed but take all the screen (the text does not appear, even if I remove the "modifier.fillMaxSize()"
I saw that there was another method the "fillViewPort" argument with the ScrollView composable but I am not sure if there is a simple way with my code ?
Here is my code :
MyApp {

            val context = LocalContext.current

                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())

                ) {
                    AndroidView(
                        factory = {
                            PieChart(context).apply {
                                val entries = listOf(
                                    PieEntry(40f, "January"),
                                    PieEntry(30f, "February"),
                                    PieEntry(20f, "March"),
                                    PieEntry(10f, "April")
                                )

                                val dataSet = PieDataSet(entries, "Datas").apply {
                                    colors = listOf(
                                        android.graphics.Color.RED,
                                        android.graphics.Color.GREEN,
                                        android.graphics.Color.BLUE,
                                        android.graphics.Color.YELLOW
                                    )
                                }
                                data = PieData(dataSet)
                            }
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
                    )

                    for (i in 1..50) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Item $i"
                        )
                }
            }
        }


try setting modifier to wrapContentSize
